# Unknown output for Coleman-Liau index program

Tags: c, cs50

I've been doing the CS50 course this week and I am stuck on this simple problem, because I don't know how to find my mistake, every time I input test text such as:

*Harry Potter was a highly unusual boy in many ways. For one thing, he hated the summer holidays more than any other time of year. For another, he really wanted to do his homework, but was forced to do it in secret, in the dead of the night. And he also happened to be a wizard.*

Which should output **Grade 5** instead of **Grade 2**.
Here is the link to the walkthrough:
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/

I wrote this code for it, I also would know if there is work around the SIZE, because the more text the more space we would need, and thus I suspect 1024 is not sufficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 1024

char text[SIZE];
int main(void){

    gets(text);
    int length,letters=0, sentences=1, words=1; //word and sentence start from 1 as it's the minimum value

    length = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if(isalpha(text[i])){
            letters++;
        }
        if(text[i]==('.'|'!'|','|';')) {
            sentences++;
        }
        if(isspace(text[i])) {
            words++;
        }


    }


    double index= ((5.88*(letters/words))-(0.296*sentences/words)-(15.8));
    if(index<0){
        printf("Before grade 1\n");
    } else if (index>16){
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }else{
        printf("Grade: %.f",index);
    }

    // printf("l: %d\ns: %d\nw: %d\n",letter,sentence,word); this was used to check if counters were correct



}
```

Comment: "I don't know how to find my mistake". That's referred to as debugging. So are you saying you don't know how to debug effectively? If so, that's well worth learning first. At this level the best way is to use a debugger to step through the code and examine it as it runs.

Comment: From the tips section: `You might want to cast your one or more values to float before performing division when calculating L and S!` `letters`, `sentences`, and `words` are ints, so `letters/words` is integer division. Do you need those `()`? The text you're working with is 226 characters, so `SIZE` is fine. If it worries you then making it larger won't hurt anything.

Comment: There are some other issues in your code as well. `if(text[i]==('.'|'!'|','|';')) {` doesn't do what you might hope, only `!?.` are supposed to indicate the end of a sentence, the sentence count should start at 0, and you're not rounding the index value. There's more, but instead of pointing them all out I'd encourage you to go back and carefully read the instructions again and compare them to your code.

Comment: `'.'|'!'|','|';'` is `'?'` assuming ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, after this weekend I had time to check your answers .
the final code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 1024


char text[SIZE];
int main(void){

    gets(text);
    int length,letters=0, sentences=0, words=1; //word and sentence start from 1 as it's the minimum value
    length = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if(isalpha(text[i])){
            letters++;
        }
        if(text[i]=='.'|| text[i]=='!'||text[i]=='?') {
            sentences++;
        }
        if(isspace(text[i])) {
            words++;
        }
    }
    float L=(letters*100.0f/words);
    float S=(sentences*100.0f/words);


    double index= (0.0588*L-0.296*S-(15.8));
    index=round(index);
    if(index<0){
        printf("Before grade 1\n");
    } else if (index>16){
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }else{
        printf("Grade: %.f\n",index);
    }

    // printf("l: %d\ns: %d\nw: %d\n",letter,sentence,word); this was used to check if counters were correct



}
```